# link description to external website

Tags: website-design, hyperlinks

Hi I have a link on a website that goes to another website. Currently the link text which is clickable is "website". Should I include the name of the website that it clicks to since 'website' is so generic? I was thinking of using 'go to program website' as the link text. Is there a better apprpoach?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hello I have found the information I am seeking here: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H30.html